# a NYT reconstruct bringing readers

Tags: word-usage

Is "reconstruct" a verb here? If so, should it be "reconstructs"?

> NYTimes retweeted:
> JUST POSTED: The Anatomy of a Lie, **a NYT reconstruct bringing readers** behind the scenes of Trump's failed 77-day effort to subvert democracy and overturn the 2020 election.

Comment: It's a verb forced to act as a noun, where many would choose 'reconstruction'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a noun, it appears to be a new word. It has been formed from the verb "reconstruct" and meaning "reconstruction".  It's not clear to me why the NYT has chosen to make up a new noun instead of using the existing word.